# How do I delay the launch of a program

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, delayed-execution

For security reasons - I need my firewall to be set up correctly before any program that uses the internet is started - I would like to delay the manual launch of any program by, say 50 seconds. Do note that I would like to apply this policy to a program that is manually launched by the user - in my case, Google Chrome - and not to programs that come up at the startup - and for which I am already aware of solutions like Soluto.

Can this be done under Windows 7 ?

Additionally, I would be grateful if I could know how to restrict changes of this option to admin users only.

Thanks

Comment: Would the script provided by Indrek here : http://superuser.com/questions/239749/delay-windows-programs-launching-at-boot do the trick ?

Comment: Another possibility to do what I want would be to set Google Chrome as a startup program - to which I can apply delaying using known programs - and then to permanently disable the possibility to manually start it up. Is that possible ?

Comment: Don't firewalls usually start as system services – which *already* run before user programs?

Comment: Yes, but my particular firewall takes roughly 2 mins to load..